# JavaScript output is different from my answer

Tags: javascript

This question was asked during the interview at work interview my answer was recorded as wrong.

Asked Question : What is the output of this code block ?

```
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i]);
  }, 3000);
}
```

My answer is :

```
index 0 element 10
index 1 element 12
index 2 element 15
index 3 element 21
```

but it is not correct. What is the right answer ?

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`. Or, even better, use `forEach` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think the OP was supposed to show the output of given code, not write the code :p

Comment: `This question was asked`  - what is the question that was asked. We know what you are asking, but you haven't actually stated the question you answered wrong

Comment: @CertainPerformance yea I know but I asked different question please read my question

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited question. I am new. I am sorry

Comment: All good, makes sense now - and @CertainPerformance performance did answer one interpretation of the question you originally asked :p

Comment: because of the `console.log` is set and trigger after 3secound, and by that time index `i` is already loop to 4, therefore the result should be 4 line of `Index 4, element: undefined`. undefined cause of the array doesn't have the 5th slot of value

Comment: Run the snippet in browser's console and you will see the result. For explanation, @Dean response will clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the most popular javascript interview question.

```
Answer is Index: 4, element: undefined(printed 4 times).
```

The reason for this is because the setTimeout function creates a function (the closure) that has access to its outer scope, which is the loop that contains the index i. After 3 seconds go by, the function is executed and it prints out the value of i, which at the end of the loop is at 4 because it cycles through 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and the loop finally stops at 4.arr[4] does not exist, which is why you get undefined.

Comment: Can you please explain that why index inside `setTimeout()` turns out to be 4?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa I gave my answer in more detail

Answer (score 1):

Answer will be :

```
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
Index: 4, element: undefined
```

Explanation :

`setTimeout` is used here to print to console, with timeout of 3000 milliseconds or 3 seconds, by that time `for` loop will be long over, and at the end of the `for` loop, value of `i` will be 4.

Since the function inside `setTimeout` has the access to variable 'i' (Its called `closure`, read about it more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)), it will print the value of `i = 4`. And since there is no such index 4 in the `arr`, it is `undefined`.

I hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

For your answer using setTimeOut() function, You need to use IIFE - immediately-invoked function expression.
Like this

```js
const arr = [10, 12, 15, 21];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  (function(i){setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Index: ' + i + ', element: ' + arr[i]);
  }, 3000)})(i);
}
```

Because, it for every loop, the entire inner function will get executed and then only the next loop runs. Else, **setTimeout** function will create timeout events, but loop will be completed and the value of i after loop completion will be here 4 only and the corresponding array element is not there. So, it will be undefined.

For learning about this scenario, Here are some links.

- Learn about JS Closure - [freecodecamp](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-learn-javascript-closures-66feb44f6a44)
- Example of Closure concept with setTimeout - [Medium](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/es6-variable-scopes-in-loops-with-closure-9cde7a198744)